# Parsing http return broken link

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, telegram

I'am trying to parse image from some Telegram channel, as example https://t.me/versusbattlerus, the image is on this block 
"img class="tgme_page_photo_image" src="https://... " but every time method returns different and not working links, why this happens?
I'am using python 3.6, urllib, beautifulsoup4

Method

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    image = soup.find('img', class_="tgme_page_photo_image")
    print(image)
    #return image


def main():
    parse(get_html('https://t.me/versusbattlerus'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This works fine with me

Answer (score 0):

This script works on me, please provide “broken” link for the test.

If that has bugs, try simple Linux Shell solution:

```
curl -s https://t.me/SeanChannel |grep -oP '"og:image" content="\K.+(?=")'
```

Comment: sorry, you mean my script working for you? So you can open image right?

Comment: @T3h_vermili0n Yep, I can open it